# C# - WCV using class from .net core project

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core

I have some problem with my project, i'm making application in .net core but i also need to create api, i want to make "wcf service" and now i can't use class from other project in solution becouse wcf is in .net framework :\ example below.

```
namespace Example.Data //This is class library
{
    public class Assortment:MainFields
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string EANCode { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace WcfService1 //This is wcf service
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string ReturnAssortmentWithEanCode(string EANCode)
        {
            return (new Assortment(EANCode, "Test"));
        }
    }
}
```

In WcfService1 i can't use "Using Example.Data;"

Comment: Are you able to use a modern API framework instead of WCF?

Comment: Whitch one? Can you send me link or something?

Comment: If you want to go with an RPC paradigm like WCF you can [look at gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). If you want to use a REST approach [look at ASP.NET Web APIs](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/apis)

Answer (score 0):

[CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF) supports WCF servers on .net core. [Version 1.0.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/) was released recently (May 2022).

Comment: "*The goal of this project is to enable existing WCF projects to move to .NET Core.*". In my opinion, I wouldn't recommend this for new development.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look at the usage of [wcf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial),

you can define in IService1.cs and then use .net core as client to communicate with WCF service.

> For .NET Core projects, you can use the Connected Services node in
> Solution Explorer to access the Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference
> Provider, which lets you manage Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)
> data service references.
>
> [To add a reference to a service in the current solution (.NET Core projects))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2022#to-add-a-reference-to-a-service-in-the-current-solution-net-core-projects)